# Adsense ads with my own ads

Tags: google-adsense, google-adsense-policies, advertising

I have a website. It consists of Excel VBA lessons. I have put Google Adsense ads in it.
Now I want to put my own advertisements in it. (To get some freelancing programming jobs.)

For an example, assume that I have 2 Adsense ads in my website and 2 of my own ads.

Is this against the Adsense terms?

Answer (score 1):

It isn't against Adsense terms. You can use your own advertisement, your overall page/site must comply with Adsense terms and conditions.

Comment: Links to the relevent Adsense help documents would be useful here: [Using other ad networks together with AdSense](https://support.google.com/adsense/answer/9728?hl=en) and [Ad placement policies](https://support.google.com/adsense/answer/1346295#Placing_Google_ads_on_the_same_page_with_other_ads)